# Python list not adding, only replacing

Tags: python

I'm trying to make it so when you press button1 it adds "1" to the list. So pressing the button twice should make an output of [1][1]. But instead it prints just [1]. Note I'm very new to python.

```
def addnumber(a):
   numbers = []
   numbers.append(a)
   print(numbers)
button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="1", command=lambda: addnumber(1))
button2 = Button(bottomFrame, text="2", command=lambda: addnumber(2))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are reinitializing `numbers` to be an empty list inside the function. So each time you call the function, you create an empty list `numbers` and hence the previously appended values are lost. You need to move `numbers = []` outside the function. This way you just define it once as an empty list and then the items just keep appending/adding to it during each function call.

```
numbers = []

def addnumber(a):
   numbers.append(a)
   print(numbers)

button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="1", command=lambda: addnumber(1))
button2 = Button(bottomFrame, text="2", command=lambda: addnumber(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is whenever the button is hit the control goes to def addnumber(a) where you have written numbers = [] and then you are appending. The scope of numbers is in addnumbers definition only so every time it is like you are creating a new variable and then assigning to it. Try declaring it globally and then using it.

`numbers = []
def addnumber(a):
   global numbers
   numbers.append(a)
   print(numbers)
button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="1", command=lambda: addnumber(1))
button2 = Button(bottomFrame, text="2", command=lambda: addnumber(2))`